# Browser extension - how to include third part library inside background.js file

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

How I can include an npm library inside a chrome extesion that isn't using webpack? I want to call a library inside my background.js file but also if I declare the library inside the manifest background scripts section, it will not be available into background script and this error is logged: `background.js:8 Uncaught ReferenceError: lamejs is not defined`

Any help please?

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "test extension",
  "description": "test",
  "permissions": [
    "https://*",
    "webRequest",
    "activeTab",
    "downloads"
  ],
  "background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js",
      "js/lame.min.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "browser_action": {
    
  },
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'"
}
```

background.js

```
const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128);
// other code here
```

Comment: Your package needs to support a browser. That means it will have a minified (or not) version which you can use in website. You have to include that script in background scripts section of the manifest. Finally, if your package has any dependency add that in the background scripts as well.

Comment: The library is available in npm and also in browser version. The problem is that it will not recognized, see the updated question

Comment: Move `"js/lame.min.js"` before `"js/background.js"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember that the scripts are loaded linearly. This means that the order of the loaded scripts is very important. Always place your `background.js` at the end in that array. This part of your code, `const mp3encoder = new lamejs.Mp3Encoder(1, 44100, 128)` wont be available at the time you use it because you're loading `lamejs` after `background.js` has been loaded.

This is your code:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/background.js",
      "js/lame.min.js"
    ],
```

Do this instead:

```
"background": {
    "scripts": [
      "js/lame.min.js",
      "js/background.js"
    ],
```